# How to access an array in all functions in my C program?

Tags: c, arrays, tree, segment-tree

I am trying to create a segment tree for a competitive coding problem and this tree is represented using an array. I have functions namely, rangeMinQuery and updateTree which perform intermediate jobs on the array. I am unable to figure out how to manipulate the said array using the functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define bool int    
#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))

int upper_power_of_two(int v)
{
v--;
v |= v >> 1;
v |= v >> 2;
v |= v >> 4;
v |= v >> 8;
v |= v >> 16;
v++;
return v;

}

int getMid(int s, int e)
{
  return s + (e -s)/2;  
}

void updateValueUtil(int segTree[], int ss, int se, int i, int diff, int si)
{
// Base Case: If the input index lies outside the range of 
// this segment
if (i < ss || i > se)
    return;

// If the input index is in range of this node, then update 
// the value of the node and its children
st[si] = st[si] + diff;
if (se != ss)
{
    int mid = getMid(ss, se);
    updateValueUtil(st, ss, mid, i, diff, 2*si + 1);
    updateValueUtil(st, mid+1, se, i, diff, 2*si + 2);
}
}

void updateValue(int arr[], int segTree[], int n, int i, int new_val)
{
// Get the difference between new value and old value
int diff = new_val - arr[i];

// Update the value in array
arr[i] = new_val;

// Update the values of nodes in segment tree
updateValueUtil(st, 0, n-1, i, diff, 0);
}

int rangeMinquery(int segTree[],int qlow,int qhigh,int low,int high,int pos)
{
if(qlow<=low && qhigh >=high)
    return segTree[pos];

if(qlow>high || qhigh <low)
        return 9999999999;
int mid=(low+high)/2;
return MAX(rangeMinquery(segTree,qlow,qhigh,low,mid,2*pos+1),rangeMinquery(segTree,qlow,qhigh,mid+1,high,2*pos+2));
}

int main()
{
int n,q,x,l,r,i;
scanf("%d %d %d %d",&n,&q,&l,&r);
int a[n];
int segTree[upper_power_of_two(n)];
printf("%d\n",upper_power_of_two(n));
while(q--)
{
    int cmd,pos1,pos2;
    scanf("%d %d %d",&cmd,&pos1,&pos2);
    if(cmd==1)
    {
        a[pos1]+=pos2;
        updateValue(a,segTree,n,1,0);
    }
    if(cmd==2)
    {
        x=rangeMinquery(segTree,pos1,pos2,0,n,0);
        printf("%d\n",x);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to manipulate the array **segTree** and retain the values there itself. I would also like to know if there's a method to achieve the same on JAVA perhaps?

Comment: C [have a `bool` type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean), `#include <stdbool.h>` and use it instead of your macro.

Comment: oh thank you. I'll do that :)

Comment: `return MAX(rangeMinquery(segTree,...`  Will cause **a lot** of function calls...

Comment: That's how the algorithm works.. anyway; that's not what I'm looking for. I want to know how I can access manipulate this array, make it global for all functions.

Comment: you need to pass the segtree array as pass by reference to your function calls. [check here how](http://c-language.com/c-tutorial/c-functions/c-pass-reference/)

Answer (score 0):

You can make global pointer...

```
//in global scope
int *segTree;
```

... and create array using `malloc()` operator:

```
//in main()
segTree = malloc(upper_power_of_two(n) * sizeof(int));
```

And now your array is global. But remember to `free(segTree)` before you end your program.

Btw. You should **never** create local arrays (on stack) with variable size like you did in given code.